# What's the mean of " H1(s) be the least element in the set"?

Tags: analysis

> The following statements are equivalent: (a) $S$ is a countable set. (b) There exists a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$. (c) There exists an injection of $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$
>
> *Proof $(b)\implies(c)$*: If $H$ is a surjection of $\mathbb{N}$ onto $S$, we define $H_1:S\to \mathbb{N}$ by letting $H_1(s)$ be the least element in the set $H^{-1}(s)$:={$n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ : $H(n)$=$s$}. To see that $H_1$ is an injection of  $S$ into $\mathbb{N}$, note that if $s$,$t$ $\in$ $S$ and $n_{st}:=H_1(s)=H_1(t)$.

My question is: What's the mean of " $H_1(s)$ be the least element in the set" ?
$$\begin{matrix}  N & S  \\ 1 & a_1  \\ 2 & a_2 \\ 3 & a_3 \\ .  &  .     \\   .  &  .     \\   .  &  .     \\  n  &  a_n     \\   n+1  &        \\    .   &        \\    .   &        \\ \end{matrix}$$
Let's say S is finite, How could H1(s) be the least? Like if $a_1$ maps to preimage 1 and 2, then 1 is the least?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $H_1(s)$ is the smallest number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $H(n)=s$ (there is always at least one since $H$ is surjective).

Comment: Let's say $H(1)=s_1, H(2)=s_1$, so 1 is the smallest number of $H_1(s_1)$. Am I right?   @Captain Lama

Comment: It's not "the smallest number of $H_1(s_1)$", it is just $H_1(s_1)$ (maybe that's what you meant, but I'm not sure). If $H(1)=s$, it is always the case that $H_1(s)=1$ since you seem to be using the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ starts with $1$. But if $H(4)=s$ for instance, then $H_1(s)=4$ only if $H(1)$, $H(2)$ and $H(3)$ are different from $s$.